# What's wrong in the 'for' loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, math

So, while writing some code to calculate a total of a shopping list, I wrote this code (at Codecademy):

```
    shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            total = total + prices[item]
            value = stock[item] - 1
            return value
    return total
```

Now, when I run it, it doesn't give an error, but it says it gives the answer '5' when 1 pear, apple, and banana are on the shopping list, instead of '7'. I have looked through the code, and just can't find where I went wrong.

Comment: Please add the function call too.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that? This is everything that I have.

Comment: What is the value of `food`?

Comment: 1 apple, 1 pear and 1 banana. This is the value that is used.

Comment: You return `value` as soon as you find a matching `item` in `stock`

Comment: You have `6` bananas, take away `1` and return the result, `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `return value` from the for loop :

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            total += prices[item]
            #remove item from stock 
            stock[item] -= 1
    return total
```

Note that with your input data, there's no apple in stock. So it's only possible to buy one banana and one orange from your shopping list, for a total price of `5.5` :

```
print compute_bill(shopping_list)
5.5
stock : {'orange': 31, 
         'pear': 15, 
         'banana': 5, 
         'apple': 0}
```